# Show Command Buttons Conditionally on hierarchy telerik grid

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, grid

I want to show a custom command button in a telerik grid hierachy depending on the master-row data

Hi, I have a telerik hierarchy grid data, and I want to show a custom command button in the detail row, depending on the master-row data.

in the detail template grid, i call  the ShowIfSubmitted() method.

```
command.Custom("Void").Text("Void").Click("VoidDeal").Visible("ShowIfSubmitted");
```

In the function:

```
function ShowIfSubmitted(dataItem) {

}
```

I only can access to the model data in the detail row.

But I want to access de master-row data, to check if the value of the property in the model meets the criteria to hide the button in the detail row.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(arguments)` inside the `ShowIfSubmitted` function ?

Comment: The `console.log(arguments)` gives the instance object of the current row, so that does not work for me. My workaround was to extract the parent row instance model in order to get its id, with this field I created and ajax call to the DB to get all the info that I needed. Actually, with the "arguments" object, I could have extracted the id value.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

My workaround was to extract the parent row instance model in order to get its id, with this field I created and ajax call to the DB to get all the info that I needed. Actually, with the "arguments" object, I could have extracted the id value.

Basically I just did this:

```
function ShowIfSubmitted(dataItem) { 
    var deal_status_id = 0; 
    $.ajax({ 
        async: false, 
        data: { dealId: dataItem.Deal_Number }, 
        url: '@Url.Action("action", "controller")', 
        success: function (data) { 
            deal_status_id = data; 
        } 
    }) 
    return deal_status_id == submitted_status; 
}
```

In the controller action is where I call the service.

Comment: You could add some code of your solution to help futher users